# Simple mod-rewrite issue

Tags: mod-rewrite

I am tring to accomplish simple task using mod-rewrite

I need url of such kind

**http://localhost/docs/path/to/a/file/somefile_without_extension?d=file.txt**

became downloadable so user will download a file with name file.txt as attachment
I use something like this trying to make it working but it not. Please note

> somefile_without_extension

is normal image for example

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^/ ?d={d} 

Header  set Content-disposition  "attachment; filename=%{d}e" env=d
```

Comment: RewriteRule ^/ should be RewriteRule ^/(.*)$ or RewriteRule ^/$

Comment: yes thanks, I tried but it not downloads, if this is image it just shows it

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
 RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^(.*)[\&|\?]*d=([\w|\d|\.|\%|]*)[\&]*(.*)$
 RewriteRule   .*  - [E=FILENAME:%2]

 Header set "Content-disposition" "attachment; filename=%{FILENAME}e" env=FILENAME
 UnsetEnv FILENAME
```